# How to find the "area" of a box (hyperrectangle) projected onto a ball (hypersphere)?

Tags: metric-geometry

What is the "area" of the general $n-1$ - box (hyperrectangle) projected onto the surface of the general $n$ - ball (hypersphere)?

Is there a known closed-form solution?

I'm just curious. Thanks!

Comment: There a lot of different projections. What projection you are interested in? I suspect it is either central or orthogonal. Anyway, please, specify.

Comment: I think you could just integrate a term depending on the angle over the rectangle. This works for all shapes and should lead to a 'closed form' if there is one.